# Reverse SSH Tunnel over SOCKS5

Tags: ssh, proxy, port-forwarding

Edit: It could be broken to a simpler problem, I believe: If I run `proxychains4 wget http://localhost:8080` then it wouldn't work aswell. I have turned off `proxy_dns` but it did not help.

I have a SOCKS5 proxy set up; the proxy server is another machine in the same subnet, which is connected to the router. It's a bit more complicated than that but it must go through that and the first machine cannot be connected to the router.

That being said, I have an online server and I want it to listen on port 8080 and forward requests to my inner machine (the one which i've talked about above) on port 8080. So this is what I do:

`proxychains4 ssh foxy@my-static-addr.htz-classic-177-42-77-8.org -R 0.0.0.0:8080:0.0.0.0:8080 -N`

The tunnel is being opened and I can connect the server on that port but once I try to request the file, something goes wrong and I don't receive the HTTP response. I have a web server running on port 8080 on the inner machine.

Any idea what I could do to fix this?

Comment: is "0.0.0.0" just to hide real IPs you  actually use or it used like that ?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is to listen on all interfaces, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: If it runs on windows it could be a problem with 0.0.0.0. I still can't get it your connection schema, try `ssh -N -R 8080:localhost:8080 foxy@my-static-addr.htz-classic-177-42-77-8.org`

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it that way too. Doesn't seem to work. It's not windows so no worries.@Alex

Comment: Try to test first just ssh remote reverse tunnel, without `proxychains4` to be make sure tunnel is working as it should

Comment: It does work if I do it from another computer, so it's probably really the proxychains4. @Alex